# Deriving the probability on the Probability of an Event - Chebyshev's Theorem

Tags: probability, statistics

Question: For the random variable X, where E(X) = 0 and Var(X) = 1, derive the upper bound on the probability of the event $\{|X-.6| > .2\}$.

My attempt: Using Chebyshev's Inequality- Prob($|X-E(X)| > \epsilon) \leq \frac{Var(X)}{\epsilon^2} = \frac{1}{(.2)^2} = 25.$

A) With no distributional assumption is this correct? I am thinking that because the probability is greater than 1 then this is a trivial inequality. I have seen alternate definitions of Chebyshev's inequality where $\epsilon$ is $k \sigma$ and if k is greater than or equal to 1 then this happens. However, 25 seems like an unusual number to get. Am I missing something?

B) As a follow up and for further understanding, how would the probability change if X was normally distributed with mean = 0 and variance = 1? Using the probability normal approximation integral I get the probability to be 3.96953... Although 25 and 3.96 are very different, is accuracy even a question since both probabilities are greater than 1?

Comment: $E[X]=0$ not $0.6$. So the probablity you're calculating is $P(|X|\ge.2)$

Comment: Also, assuming normal distribution, $P(|X-.6|>.2)=P(X>0.8 or X<0.4)$ which is equal to approx $0.867$

Answer (score 1):

You misused Chebyshev's inequality. You computed $P(|X|> .2)$ not $P(|X-.6|>.2)$. Using Markov's inequality (i.e. Chebyshev's) we get $$P(|X-.6|>.2)=P((X-.6)^2>.04)\le\frac{E(X-.6)^2}{.04}=\frac{1-0+.36}{.04}$$

Still, this is greater than $1$. This is to be expected. Consider $X$ to be a coinflip with $50/50$ shot of $\pm 1$. Then $E(X)=0, \operatorname{var}(X)=1$. And for all $\varepsilon<1$ we have $$P(|X|>\varepsilon)=1$$

You can modify this for the case of $|X-.6|$.

So the best bound we can get is $1$ without further information.